# How to bind a list of list to a view?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

There are 2 classes. One is a parent that contain a list of the second class as a property.
The second class has a list also.

The problem is the application doesn't bind the list inside the second class.

The application will display a list of grid that bind from the second class list (in the parent class) and each grid will display information from the list inside the second class.

Now each grid doesn't bind value

```
Class Parent{
   public List<NestedClass> Child { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}

Class NestedClass{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeParameter> Params{ get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello world";                
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

The xaml as below.

```
    <ItemsControl  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource ="{Binding Child}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Child.Params}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1"></Grid>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="2"></Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The output window show as below

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Params' property not found on 'object' ''NestedClass' (HashCode=16626097)'. BindingExpression:Path=Params; DataItem='NestedClass' (HashCode=16626097); target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

**Edited#1** Added the xaml

**Edited#2** Added the output message

**Edited#3** Added the name property in the NestedClass

Comment: Have you tried to set ItemsSource of inner ItemsControl to Params?

Comment: @Sascha Do you mean `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Params}" >` right? If it right, I have tried already. It doesn't work.

Comment: @groupgrip, did you try <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Child.Params}"> ?

Comment: @VasiliiRuzov Yes, i have tried it. As the sample code I put in the question. It doesn't work.

Comment: Those inner `Grid`s are horrendous. Why are they needed?

Comment: @groupgrip, check your data context. It seems like it's wrong. Does the binding to Child work fine? If it works good, try to restart VS. I had similar problems. VS sometimes shows some strange errors

Comment: @VasiliiRuzov For the child it works fine, I tested with the other property inside the child. It can show the property.

Comment: @Gusdor Sorry, I don't know how to answer your question. ^^

Comment: @groupgrip, please, look at last example on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) page. I think, you create ItemsControl in wrong way. If you want to show the list of grids, so the outer <DataTemplate> must contain <Grid>, but not one more <ItemsControl>.

Comment: @VasiliiRuzov Thank you so much. I found that is my bad. I declare it as a field. So, it doesn't recognize. And it work fine when I changed to be a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you tried it or not and whether it worked or not, the correct way to do this is as @groupgrip mentioned:

```
<ItemsControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Child}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Params}">
                ...
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` will be set to an item from the `Child` collection which is of type `NestedClass`. This class has a property called `Params`, so we can `Bind` directly with that property from inside the `DataTemplate`. There should also be a property named `Count` in that class as you are also trying to `Bind` to that from inside the `DataTemplate`.

Either way, the way to fix these types of problems on your own is to read what the errors say in the Output Window of Visual Studio. You often get errors that say something like 'can't find this property on that object' which should help you to track down and fix any problems.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to check the output window. `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Params' property not found on 'object' ''NestedClass' (HashCode=16626097)'. BindingExpression:Path=Params; DataItem='NestedClass' (HashCode=16626097); target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')` It said like this. I still don't know why it doesn't recognize. Please help.

Comment: Well you're right... it didn't like that. I can only assume that you *don't* have that property defined in your class like you have shown. Is the property not defined as `public`, or is there a spelling mistake or something. Look at your `Count` property if it is not complaining about that one... there must be a difference in the declarations of those two properties.

Comment: Thank you. This is my bad. In the sample i put  is correct but the code i do is wrong. I declare it as field not a property.

Comment: @groupgrip, to avoid such situations never retype the code to stackoverflow. Copy it

Answer (score 0):

For "Parent" class use [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for child - DataTemplate. Define both templates in resources.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Parent}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">... </>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Child}">...</>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">...</>
</Grid>
```